# CSVファイルから特定の行を削除したい

Tags: python, python3, csv

CSVファイルの情報を書き換えたいです。
車の情報が並べてあるcsvファイルがあり、ユーザーが買いたい車の番号(x)を選ぶとcsvファイルから購入された車の行が削除されるようにしたいです。csvファイルの中身は以下にペーストしました。一番左にあるのがユーザーが選ぶ番号です。30と31に価格が記入されていませんが、今回のケースでは一番左のインデックス番号しかみないはずなので関係ないかと思います。

pandasなどは使わずデフォルトの機能のみでやりたいです。自分の考えとしては元のcsvファイルにwriteモードを使って特定の行以外は元のデータからコピーして入力できたらなと思いながらコードを書きました。よろしくお願いいたします。

---

以下のようなプログラムを作りたいです。

ユーザーがバイヤーかディーラーか選ぶ。

**バイヤーの場合:**

1. 価格帯を三つの中から選択する
2. 選ばれた価格帯の車を表示する
3. 買う車の番号を選ぶ、またはプログラムを終了する
4. 購入された場合は該当の車を削除する(ここで該当の車を削除してくれず、元のままになります)

**ディーラーの場合:**

1. ユーザーが車の情報を入力する
2. ユーザーが入力した情報をファイルに書き込む

**問題点**

エラーは出ないのですが、csvファイルには以下の行のみが残ります。

```
88volvowagon104.3188.8ohcfour11423
```

---

**対象のCSV**

```
index,company,body-style,wheel-base,length,engine-type,num-of-cylinders,horsepower,average-mileage,price
0,alfa-romero,convertible,88.6,168.8,dohc,four,111,21,13495
1,alfa-romero,convertible,88.6,168.8,dohc,four,111,21,16500
2,alfa-romero,hatchback,94.5,171.2,ohcv,six,154,19,16500
3,audi,sedan,99.8,176.6,ohc,four,102,24,13950
4,audi,sedan,99.4,176.6,ohc,five,115,18,17450
5,audi,sedan,99.8,177.3,ohc,five,110,19,15250
6,audi,wagon,105.8,192.7,ohc,five,110,19,18920
9,bmw,sedan,101.2,176.8,ohc,four,101,23,16430
10,bmw,sedan,101.2,176.8,ohc,four,101,23,16925
11,bmw,sedan,101.2,176.8,ohc,six,121,21,20970
13,bmw,sedan,103.5,189,ohc,six,182,16,30760
14,bmw,sedan,103.5,193.8,ohc,six,182,16,41315
15,bmw,sedan,110,197,ohc,six,182,15,36880
16,chevrolet,hatchback,88.4,141.1,l,three,48,47,5151
17,chevrolet,hatchback,94.5,155.9,ohc,four,70,38,6295
18,chevrolet,sedan,94.5,158.8,ohc,four,70,38,6575
19,dodge,hatchback,93.7,157.3,ohc,four,68,31,6377
20,dodge,hatchback,93.7,157.3,ohc,four,68,31,6229
27,honda,wagon,96.5,157.1,ohc,four,76,30,7295
28,honda,sedan,96.5,175.4,ohc,four,101,24,12945
29,honda,sedan,96.5,169.1,ohc,four,100,25,10345
30,isuzu,sedan,94.3,170.7,ohc,four,78,24,6785
31,isuzu,sedan,94.5,155.9,ohc,four,70,38,
32,isuzu,sedan,94.5,155.9,ohc,four,70,38,
33,jaguar,sedan,113,199.6,dohc,six,176,15,32250
34,jaguar,sedan,113,199.6,dohc,six,176,15,35550
35,jaguar,sedan,102,191.7,ohcv,twelve,262,13,36000
36,mazda,hatchback,93.1,159.1,ohc,four,68,30,5195
37,mazda,hatchback,93.1,159.1,ohc,four,68,31,6095
38,mazda,hatchback,93.1,159.1,ohc,four,68,31,6795
39,mazda,hatchback,95.3,169,rotor,two,101,17,11845
43,mazda,sedan,104.9,175,ohc,four,72,31,18344
44,mercedes-benz,sedan,110,190.9,ohc,five,123,22,25552
45,mercedes-benz,wagon,110,190.9,ohc,five,123,22,28248
46,mercedes-benz,sedan,120.9,208.1,ohcv,eight,184,14,40960
47,mercedes-benz,hardtop,112,199.2,ohcv,eight,184,14,45400
49,mitsubishi,hatchback,93.7,157.3,ohc,four,68,37,5389
50,mitsubishi,hatchback,93.7,157.3,ohc,four,68,31,6189
51,mitsubishi,sedan,96.3,172.4,ohc,four,88,25,6989
52,mitsubishi,sedan,96.3,172.4,ohc,four,88,25,8189
53,nissan,sedan,94.5,165.3,ohc,four,55,45,7099
54,nissan,sedan,94.5,165.3,ohc,four,69,31,6649
55,nissan,sedan,94.5,165.3,ohc,four,69,31,6849
56,nissan,wagon,94.5,170.2,ohc,four,69,31,7349
57,nissan,sedan,100.4,184.6,ohcv,six,152,19,13499
61,porsche,hardtop,89.5,168.9,ohcf,six,207,17,34028
62,porsche,convertible,89.5,168.9,ohcf,six,207,17,37028
63,porsche,hatchback,98.4,175.7,dohcv,eight,288,17,
66,toyota,hatchback,95.7,158.7,ohc,four,62,35,5348
67,toyota,hatchback,95.7,158.7,ohc,four,62,31,6338
68,toyota,hatchback,95.7,158.7,ohc,four,62,31,6488
69,toyota,wagon,95.7,169.7,ohc,four,62,31,6918
70,toyota,wagon,95.7,169.7,ohc,four,62,27,7898
71,toyota,wagon,95.7,169.7,ohc,four,62,27,8778
79,toyota,wagon,104.5,187.8,dohc,six,156,19,15750
80,volkswagen,sedan,97.3,171.7,ohc,four,52,37,7775
81,volkswagen,sedan,97.3,171.7,ohc,four,85,27,7975
82,volkswagen,sedan,97.3,171.7,ohc,four,52,37,7995
86,volkswagen,sedan,97.3,171.7,ohc,four,100,26,9995
87,volvo,sedan,104.3,188.8,ohc,four,114,23,12940
88,volvo,wagon,104.3,188.8,ohc,four,114,23,13415
```

**現状のコード**

```
import csv

options = input("Please enter 1 if you are a buyer and please enter 2 if you are a dealer")

if options == "1":

    Range = input("Input 1 if you are looking for a car that costs between $0 to $15000\n"
                  "Input 2 if you are looking for the one costs between $15000 to $30000\n"
                  "Input 3 if you are looking for the one costs more than $30000: ")
    # open the inventory file
    infile = open("Automobile_data.csv", "r")
    # line = infile.readlines()

    header = next(infile)
    pricerangeL = 0
    pricerangeH = 15000
    if Range == "2":
        pricerangeL = 15000
        pricerangeH = 30000
    elif Range == "3":
        pricerangeL = 30000
        pricerangeH = 10000000

    for line in infile:
        line = line[:-1].split(",")

        if line[9] == "":
            continue

        elif eval(line[9]) <= pricerangeH and eval(line[9]) >= pricerangeL:
            print(line)

    infile.close()


    x = input("Please enter the number of the car you would like to buy or enter exit: ")

    if x == "exit":
         quit()


    else:
        file = open("Automobile_data.csv", "r")
        lines = file.readlines()
        file.close()


        outfile = open("Automobile_data.csv", "w")
        size = lines.__len__()
        for i in range(size - 1):
            if i == "x":
                continue
            else:
                outfile.write(lines[i])

        outfile.close()

elif options == "2":

    Index = input("Index:")
    Company = input("Company:")
    BodyStyle = input("Body Style:")
    WheelBase = input("Wheel Base:")
    Length = input("Length:")
    EngineType = input("Engine Type:")
    NumCyl = input("Number of Cylinders:")
    HorsePW = input("Horsepower:")
    AV_mil = input("Average Mileage:")
    Price = input("Price:")

    NewCar = [Index, Company, BodyStyle, WheelBase, Length, EngineType, NumCyl, HorsePW, AV_mil, Price]
    with open(r'Automobile_data.csv', 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(NewCar)
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

質問のプログラムの下記部分

```
    file = open("Automobile_data.csv", "r")
    lines = file.readlines()
    file.close()

    outfile = open("Automobile_data.csv", "w")
    size = lines.__len__()
    for i in range(size - 1):
        if i == "x":
            continue
        else:
            outfile.write(lines[i])


    outfile.close()
```

を次のように修正しては如何でしょう。

```
    file = open("Automobile_data.csv", "r")
    lines = file.readlines()
    file.close()

    outfile = open("Automobile_data.csv", "w")
    size = lines.__len__()
    for i in range(size - 1):
        lineData = lines[i].split(",") //入力ファイルのi行目をカンマで分割する
        if lineData[0] == x:  // 分割した第１項目(車の番号)と、入力された買いたい車の番号(x)が一致したら、
            continue // その行は書き出さない。
        else:      
            outfile.write(lines[i])  // 買いたい車の番号と一致しない行なので、ファイルに書きだす。

    outfile.close() // 最後にファイルを閉じる
```

Answer (score 1):

④の処理だけでなく色々と見直して以下のようにしてみました。
主に`####`でコメントした所が修正点です。

```
import csv

#### csvファイルの読み込みは処理にかかわらず最初に行い、2次元リストとして読み込んでおく
with open('Automobile_data.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    header = next(csvfile)
    fulldata = [l for l in csv.reader(csvfile)]

options = input("Please enter 1 if you are a buyer and please enter 2 if you are a dealer")

if options == "1":

    Range = input("Input 1 if you are looking for a car that costs between $0 to $15000\n"
                  "Input 2 if you are looking for the one costs between $15000 to $30000\n"
                  "Input 3 if you are looking for the one costs more than $30000: ")

    pricerangeL = 0
    pricerangeH = 15000
    if Range == "2":
        pricerangeL = 15000
        pricerangeH = 30000
    elif Range == "3":
        pricerangeL = 30000
        pricerangeH = 10000000

    #### 選択された価格帯の車情報を抽出し、そのインデックス番号も別途リスト化する
    selected = [l for l in fulldata if l[9] != '' and int(l[9]) <= pricerangeH and int(l[9]) >= pricerangeL]
    selindex = [l[0] for l in selected]

    #### 選択された価格帯の車情報を表示する
    for l in selected:
        print(l)

    x = input("Please enter the number of the car you would like to buy or enter exit: ")

    if x == "exit":
        quit()

    #### 指定されたインデックス番号が選択された価格帯のリストに存在しない時は終了する
    elif x not in selindex:
        print('The car with that number does not exist or is out of range.')
        quit()

    else:  #### この部分が④相当の新しい処理
        #### 指定されたインデックス番号の車情報を除いた新しいリストを作成する
        newdata = [l for l in fulldata if l[0] != x]

        #### 新しいリスト全体をヘッダーと共にcsvファイルとして書き出す
        with open('Automobile_data.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
            csvfile.write(header)
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
            writer.writerows(newdata)

elif options == "2":

    #### csvファイル内情報のすべてのインデックス番号を別途リスト化
    fullindex = [l[0] for l in fulldata]

    Index = input("Index:")

    #### 既に存在するインデックス番号か判定し、存在するなら終了する
    #### (既存情報を書き変える処理にしてもよいが複雑化するのでこの回答では行わない)
    if Index in fullindex:
        print('That index already exists.')
        quit()

    Company = input("Company:")
    BodyStyle = input("Body Style:")
    WheelBase = input("Wheel Base:")
    Length = input("Length:")
    EngineType = input("Engine Type:")
    NumCyl = input("Number of Cylinders:")
    HorsePW = input("Horsepower:")
    AV_mil = input("Average Mileage:")
    Price = input("Price:")

    NewCar = [Index, Company, BodyStyle, WheelBase, Length, EngineType, NumCyl, HorsePW, AV_mil, Price]
    with open('Automobile_data.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(NewCar)
    #### 不要な f.close() は削除
```

Answer (score 1):

冗長な部分が多いのと入力値のチェックが為されていないので、全体的に書き直してみました。

```py
import sys
import re

CAR_CSV_FILE = 'Automobile_data.csv'

def user_input(prompt):
  try:
    ret = input(prompt)
  except EOFError:
    print('done', file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(0)
  return ret

def user_input_integer(prompt):
  try:
    n = int(user_input(prompt))
  except ValueError as e:
    print(e, file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)
  return n

def buyer():
  price_range = ((0, 15000), (15000, 30000), (30000, float('inf')))
  p = iter(sum(price_range, ()))
  prange = user_input_integer(f'''
    Input 1 if you are looking for a car that costs between ${next(p)} to ${next(p)}
    Input 2 if you are looking for the one costs between ${next(p)} to ${next(p)}
    Input 3 if you are looking for the one costs more than ${next(p)}
    ? '''.replace('    ', ''))
  if prange < 1 or prange > len(price_range): quit()
  prange -= 1
  with open(CAR_CSV_FILE, 'r') as f:
    car_data = f.readlines()
  for car in car_data[1:]:
    car = car.strip()
    price = car.split(',')[-1].strip()
    try:
      price = int(price)
    except ValueError:
      continue
    if price_range[prange][0] <= price <= price_range[prange][1]:
      print(car)

  no = user_input(
    'Please enter the number of the car you would like to buy or enter exit: ')
  if no.strip() == 'exit': quit()
  with open(CAR_CSV_FILE, 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(
      ''.join(car for car in car_data if not re.match(rf'^{no},', car)))

def dealer():
  prompts = (
    'Index:', 'Company:', 'Body Style:', 'Wheel Base:', 'Length:',
    'Engine Type:', 'Number of Cylinders:', 'Horsepower:',
    'Average Mileage:', 'Price:')
  new_car = []
  for p in prompts:
    new_car.append(user_input(p))
  with open(CAR_CSV_FILE, 'a') as outfile:
    outfile.write(','.join(new_car))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  prompt = 'Please enter 1 if you are a buyer and please enter 2 if you are a dealer: '
  n = user_input_integer(prompt)
  if n == 1:
    buyer()
  elif n == 2:
    dealer()
```

Answer (score 1):

#### 処理方法(一例として)

データ投入時

- CSVファイル中の1行を1ファイルとしてデータを作成する

データ処理時

- 購入したファイルは削除

  - もしくは「購入済み」ディレクトリに移動。

成果物作成時

- 残っているファイルを纏めてCSVファイルを作る

#### 留意点

次の操作はアトミック（途切れることのない1つの処理）として実行される必要があります。

1. 購入対象の存在を確認
2. 購入処理

対策が取られている（※「対策は取らない」という合意も含む）のであれば、他の回答を参考にしてください。プログラム上で対策するのであれば「python セマフォ」で調べてください。